# ffmpeg. How to apply checkerboard effect like this but with 4x4 squares?

Tags: ffmpeg

**ffmpeg**. How to apply checkerboard effect like this but with 4x4 squares?

`ffmpeg -i input-image-1.png -i input-image-2.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='if(eq(mod(X,2),mod(Y,2)),A,B)'" output-image.png`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first value of the mod arguments.

```
all_expr='if(eq(mod(floor(X/4),2),mod(floor(Y/4),2)),A,B)'
```

The generic form is

```
all_expr='if(eq(mod(floor(X/N),2),mod(floor(Y/N),2)),A,B)'
```

where N is the period in pixels for color step.